# C Macro define a variable to itself with double quotes

Tags: c-preprocessor

I don't know how to describe my question in the title precisely.

What I want the final result of macro expansion to be:

```
#define HELLO "HELLO"
#define WORLD "WORLD"
```

But there could be tons of *repetitions*, as you can see there are 2 `HELLO` and 2 `WORLD` above, which should always be the same, according to my need.

What I want to achieve when writing the macro:

```
// #define DEFINE_VAR_WITH_QUOTES...
// usage:
DEFINE_VAR_WITH_QUOTES(HELLO)
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible?

No, it is not possible.

Use external tool to generate your file.

Comment: I should've thought of external tools, thanks.

Comment: OVerall, it's kind of odd, because with `#` operator you can stringify any text, so just `#define STRING(x) #x` and then `STRING(HELLO)`, but anyway.